# Comparing first and second ranks with dplyr with variable order

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following data:

```
library(tidyverse)

data = tribble(
  ~foo, ~mean, ~ci,
  "A", 1, 0.5,
  "B", 1.2, 0.3,
  "C", 3, 0.5
)
```

I want to find out if there is a significant winner in the `foo` instances, where "significant winner" means that `mean` + `ci` of the `foo` ranking first is lower than `mean` - `ci` of the `foo` ranking second.

In the above example, if the highest mean was the best, `C` would win, since *(3 - 0.5) > (1.2 + 0.3)*.

Conversely, if the lowest mean was the best, `A` would not win, since *(1 + 0.5) > (1.2 - 0.3)*.

I currently have this function implemented, assuming that the highest mean determines the winner:

```
data %>% 
summarize(
  has_winner = ifelse(
      # lower bound of first place
      (first(mean, order_by = desc(mean)) - first(ci, order_by = desc(mean))) -
        # upper bound of second place
        (nth(mean, 2, order_by = desc(mean)) + nth(ci, 2, order_by = desc(mean)))
      > 0, TRUE, FALSE
  )
)
```

What I want to do is make that function more generic. If I wanted to use it for data in which the lowest mean wins, I'd have to replace all instances of `desc()` with … well, I'm not sure. There's no `asc`, so the only thing I could come up with was removing `desc()` entirely and wrapping everything in a huge `if/else`. Obviously, that's not very nice.

How could I do that instead? In other words: When I have dynamic ordering, how do I easily compare values between first vs. second-ranked?

I know I can use `top_n` with a negative index, so in order to get the winner, I could write a rather kludgy function that uses `top_n(., 1, wt = mean) %>% pluck("mean")`, but once I have to compare that mean with the second row's mean, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I found was using the `nth` function with negative indices. This way, the order can be ascending by default, and whether you pick the first and second, or first and second to last depend on the index being positive or negative:

```
higher_is_better = TRUE
multiplier = ifelse(higher_is_better, -1, 1)

data %>% 
summarize(
  has_winner = ifelse(
    (nth(mean, multiplier, order_by = mean) - nth(ci, multiplier, order_by = mean)) -
      (nth(mean, 2 * multiplier, order_by = mean) + nth(ci, 2 * multiplier, order_by = mean))
    > 0, TRUE, FALSE
  )
)
```

For example:

```
data %>% 
  summarize(
    first_mean = nth(mean, multiplier, order_by = mean),
    second_mean = nth(mean, 2 * multiplier, order_by = mean)
  )
```

Gives:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  first_mean second_mean
       <dbl>       <dbl>
1          3         1.2
```